# How to write Cost Explorer API request with filter to get the costs exclusive of the credits?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cost-explorer

Below is the boto3 request to invoke AWS Cost API to fetch the linkedAccount Costs. **How can I add a filter to this such that I get the cost excluding the credits?**

```
client = boto3.client('ce')

request = {
        'TimePeriod' : {
            'Start': start_date,
            'End': end_date
        },
        'Granularity' : granularity,
        "GroupBy": [
            {
                "Type": "DIMENSION",
                "Key": "LINKED_ACCOUNT"
            }
        ],
        "Metrics" : [ 'UnblendedCost', 'UsageQuantity' ]
    }

    response = client.get_cost_and_usage(**request)
```

PS-
I know how to do it AWS Console. Screenshot attached[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may add a filter. Refer the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ce/client/get_cost_and_usage.html).

```
Filter={
    'Not': {
        'Dimensions': {
            'Key': 'PAYMENT_OPTION',
            'Values': [
                'Credit',
            ],
            'MatchOptions': [
                'EQUALS'
            ]
         }
    }
}
```